# Complicated double mapping over nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, map

I have a list that each term consist of two parts. First part is a graph and second is a list of pairs of vertices that I want to find graph distance of.

```
list={{ImportString[">>graph6<<EK?_"],{{4,5},{2,6},{5,6}}},{ImportString[">>graph6<<HK?g_O?"],{{2,8},{7,8},{8,9}}},{ImportString[">>graph6<<KK?g_O@?_??C"],{{10,11},{10,12},{1,7}}}}
```

[image]

This means I want distances between vertices `{4,5}`, `{2,6}` and `{5,6}` of the first graph and so on...

I want the output in the form:

```
{{{{4,5},∞},{{2,6},2},{{5,6},∞}},{{{2,8},4},{{7,8},∞},{{8,9},∞}},{{{10,11},∞},{{10,12},∞},{{1,7},2}}}
```

I can map like `GraphDistance[#[[1]],#[[2]]]&/@list` but this does not work, of course, because it should be also mapped over `#[[2]]` like `Sequence[#]&/@#[[2]]`. I can not figure out how to double-map it.

Comment: There are several different approaches you can take. One of them being: ``Map[d |-> ({{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, GraphDistance[d[[1]], #[[1]], #[[2]]]} & /@ d[[2]]), list]``

Comment: How di you do that? :-D It works, but I do not understand how it works.

Comment: @Domen: Your code can be shortened to `Map[d|->({#,GraphDistance[d[[1]],Sequence@@#]}&/@d[[2]]),list]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Domen's comment:

```
list={{ImportString[">>graph6<<EK?_"],{{4,5},{2,6},{5,6}}},{ImportString[">>graph6<<HK?g_O?"],{{2,8},{7,8},{8,9}}},{ImportString[">>graph6<<KK?g_O@?_??C"],{{10,11},{10,12},{1,7}}}};

(d|->{#,GraphDistance[d[[1]],Sequence@@#]}&/@d[[2]])/@list

Clear[list]

(* {{{{4,5},∞]},{{2,6},2},{{5,6},∞}},{{{2,8},4},{{7,8},∞},{{8,9},∞}},{{{10,11},∞},{{10,12},∞},{{1,7},2}}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd say this is the most readable way to do it:

```
MapApply[
 Function[{graph, vertices},
  MapApply[
   Function[{v1, v2}, {{v1, v2}, GraphDistance[graph, v1, v2]}], 
   vertices
   ]
  ],
 list
]
```

Note that in versions lower than 13.1, you have to use `Apply[f, list, {1}]` instead of `MapApply[f, list]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Thread`:

```
Map[{#[[2]], GraphDistance[#[[1]], Sequence @@ #[[2]]]} &, 
 Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ list, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{{4, 5}, ∞}, {{2, 6}, 2}, {{5, 6}, ∞}}, {{{2, 8}, 4}, {{7, 8}, ∞}, {{8, 9}, ∞}}, {{{10, 
>     11}, ∞}, {{10, 12}, ∞}, {{1, 7}, 2}}}
> ```